# App Engine doesn't update changes on dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, npm

I had to make a small modification in a dependency of my project, when I try it locally it works perfect. But when it is executed in app engine I have an error because it doesn't update the changes I made in the dependency. Is there a way to update dependencies when doing "gcloud app deploy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should update your dependencies in `package.json`, so that when you deploy your app those dependencies will be automatically installed by Node.js runtime.
There are some limitations that you should keep in mind.  For example, your dependencies should be Linux-compatible. Check this out with the version of your dependencies. Also, if you have specified `engines` field in your `package.json` make sure it is a compatible Node.js version. You can check the compatible version in App Engine documentation. Helpful link to troubleshoot your issue:

1. [Specifying Dependencies for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies)
2. [Node.js Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#nodejs_version)

Comment: The dependency and the original code was uploaded a month ago and it works perfect.
Today I add a functionality to the dependency, running local works perfect but when running in the app engine it generates an error, produced by not finding the code added to the dependency

Comment: Try to deploy your app using `gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache`, this will install the uncached version. Otherwise, by default fetched dependencies are cached, meaning that your new update is omitted.